# View only dashboard without access to report

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, dashboard, custom-reports, access

i want give access to user to dashboard without 
Access to report , i want hide the link in blue for example.
Thankyouuu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lightning app page on **App Builder** and you can then add your Dashboard(s) on the lightning App page. And finally, add your app page as a tab. so users can see the dashboards directly.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply but i can’t do that because i need to integrate the dashboard in community page. In community you can just add the component